# How to make $.each in jquery synchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax request that when success has an array of objects. And when I loop it using $.each it works asynchronously. I have a function inside $.each. But the code loops all then works the function after the loop. I want to loop each and execute each the function.

---

```
get_allprogram_byuser();
function get_allprogram_byuser(){
    $.ajax({
    url: ,
    type: "POST",
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        filteredarray = obj;
        filteredslice = filteredarray;


        $.each(filteredslice, function (data, data) {
            program_count = data.sp_person_count;
            alert(1);
                get_user_rank(data.sp_token, data.sp_id, data.region_id);
        });
    }
    });
}

function get_user_rank(sp_token, sp_id, region_id){

    $.ajax({
    url: "",
    type: "POST",
    data: {sp_token:sp_token,sp_id:sp_id, region_id:region_id},
    success: function (data) {
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        result = obj[0].result;
        user_id = obj[0].user_id;
        need_people = obj[0].rank;
        ranks = obj[0].ranks;
        alert('2');
        getuser_from_rank(sp_token, sp_id, region_id)
    }
    });


}


function getuser_from_rank(sp_token, sp_id, region_id){

    $.ajax({
    url: "",
    type: "POST",
    data: {sp_token:sp_token,sp_id:sp_id},
    success: function (data) {
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        filteredarray = obj;
        filteredslice = filteredarray;
        filtered =  filteredslice.filter(function(data) {
            return data;
        });
        $.each(filtered, function (data, data) {
            data['rank'] = rank_count++;
        });
        alert('3');
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: In your `$.each` callback, the parameter `data` is present twice

Comment: `$.each()` is not asynchronous.  The ajax request is.

Comment: @MaximeLaunois what do you mean? sorry I'm just a beginner

Comment: What does `get_user_rank` do?  Does it perform another ajax request?

Comment: Each is synchronous, issue is whatever get_user_rank does is not. Sounds like you need to use $.when, but would need to see more code to help out.

Comment: @Taplar yes it performs another ajax request.

Comment: Then you have a conflict there.  You cannot mix asynchronous requests with synchronous logic, unless you do something with `await`, which I'm not that familiar with.  Otherwise, you will need to restructure your logic so that it only proceeds to further ajax requests, once the previous one finishes

Comment: function get_user_rank(sp_token, sp_id, region_id){
    
    $.ajax({
    url: "someURL",
    type: "POST",
    data: {sp_token:sp_token,sp_id:sp_id, region_id:region_id},
    success: function (data) {
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        result = obj[0].result;
        user_id = obj[0].user_id;
        need_people = obj[0].rank;
        ranks = obj[0].ranks;
        getuser_from_rank(sp_token, sp_id, region_id)
    }
    });
    
}

Comment: You could use `async: false` in your ajax request. But it's better to keep it asynchronous

Comment: I have a multiple ajax request after that get_user_rank. Now what I want to do is each loop it will execute all the ajax requesst and will loop again if all the ajax request are done. How should I do that?

Comment: You should use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Ok i'll try that.

Comment: where should I put the Promise.all? in each ajax request?

Comment: No. Edit your question with all the related code. I'll put an answer

Comment: @BelowtheRadar i have already edited it sir. Please help me.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar - Sir please help me :( I'm waiting.

Comment: ok give me a moment

Answer (score 0):

For chained asynchronous request, you are better to use the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) interface that is implemented in the [jquery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
get_allprogram_byuser().then(function(data) {
    console.log("all done");
    console.log(data)
});

function get_allprogram_byuser(){
    return $.ajax({
        url: ,
        type: "POST",
        data: {},
    }).then(function(data) {
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        filteredarray = obj;
        filteredslice = filteredarray;
        return Promise.all(filteredslice.map(function(data) {
            return get_user_rank(data.sp_token, data.sp_id, data.region_id);
        });
    });
}

function get_user_rank(sp_token, sp_id, region_id){
    return $.ajax({
        url: "",
        type: "POST",
        data: {sp_token:sp_token,sp_id:sp_id, region_id:region_id},
    }).then(function(data) {
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        result = obj[0].result;
        user_id = obj[0].user_id;
        need_people = obj[0].rank;
        ranks = obj[0].ranks;
        return getuser_from_rank(sp_token, sp_id, region_id);
    });
}

function getuser_from_rank(sp_token, sp_id, region_id){
    return $.ajax({
        url: "",
        type: "POST",
        data: {sp_token:sp_token,sp_id:sp_id},
    }).then(function(data) {
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        filteredarray = obj;
        filteredslice = filteredarray;
        filtered =  filteredslice.filter(function(data) {
            return data;
        });
        $.each(filtered, function (data, data) {
            data['rank'] = rank_count++;
        });
        return data;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the function you are using in the the $.each call; Both arguments are named "data". The first argument is the index of the loop. The second is the current item. Using the index, you can separate things out a bit with a setTimeout:

https://youtu.be/LNqTRs7JJ2Q

[image]

https://gist.github.com/brianswisher/90dcf6814b76521465988cf3f567a479